# Git: disabling proxy doesn't work whatever I do

Tags: git, proxy, git-config

I'm trying to **disable the proxy** of **Git Bash** on Windows **to do a clone**, tried below commands but it still doesn't work.

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
set http_proxy=
set HTTP_PROXY=
set https_proxy=
set HTTPS_PROXY=
# And above without "set"...
# Open .gitconfig, add:
[http]
    proxy =
[https]
    proxy =
```

I've also tried running the bash prompt as administrator, still no success.
After all this **git config --list** frustratingly still prints:

```
http.proxy=http://<domain>
http.sslverify=true
http.http://*<domain>/.proxy=
http.https://*<domain>/.proxy=
http.http://*.*<domain>/.proxy=
http.https://*.*<domain>/.proxy=
http.http://*.*.*<domain>/.proxy=
http.https://*.*.*.<domain>/.proxy=
```

Of course "domain" is actually different, hidden as it's private.

Git version:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.18.0.windows.1
```

Meanwhile I'll try installing another version as I suspect this to be a git bug.

Comment: Couldn't it be your local config that's taking over? Maybe check `git config --local -l` or try to unset at local level?

Comment: Hi @RomainValeri , no, since I'm actually trying to do a clone, I'm not in a repo. "git config --local -l" prints "fatal: --local can only be used inside a git repository"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed version 2.20 and now I do all the above but list still shows the proxy there.

However cloning the repository works. Strange :)